# Usage of the slang "a man Friday" in English conversation

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

Our Boss was talking with someone and he said,

> The office clerk typist is our **man Friday**.

Does the Boss mean the *clerk typist* is the person who he/she trust?

And can I use this slang for a woman?

> The office clerk typist is our **woman Friday**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Girl_Friday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the title "Man Friday" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334311/what-does-the-title-man-friday-mean)

Comment: @NVZ How can this be duplicate of a new question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term originates from Daniel Defoe's *Robinson Crusoe*, a novel about the eponymous character, who is stranded on an island and who saves a man brought to the island  by cannibals for their main course.  The man saved from the main table as the entree is understandably grateful and becomes Crusoe's loyal servant.  The two have no common language at first, so Crusoe calls the man "[Friday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(fictional_character))" after the day of the week of their propitious encounter.

Comment: The question also asked whether the term can be used for a woman?

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/man-friday), *man Friday* means "A male personal assistant or servant".

Similar definition is found in [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/man-friday) which states *man Friday* as "a man who ​helps someone with ​their ​work and is ​loyal and can be ​trusted".

***Woman Friday***: Also, ***gal Friday***: *An efficient and faithful female assistant*, as in

> I'll have my girl Friday get the papers together.

**Update:**

Yes, following can be used:

> The office clerk typist is our woman Friday.

Comment: I have corrected a few typos. Please take a look. :)

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know about the book from 300 years ago, but the movie from 1975 seems like it would be a more modern reference. Learned scholars might refer to books that are hundreds of years old, but a movie released in many living people’s lifetime seems like it would have more of an impact on current usage.

The movie in question (Man Friday [1975]) starts with Robinson Crusoe walking along a beach on his personal stranded island, when he sees footprints. He is instantly elated at the thought of company or salvation, and goes running of to find the maker of the tracks. He comes along 4 black men, eating a 5th, cooked person (we know that they were all friends who got stranded, and in their custom, it is an honor to eat their fallen friend, who drowned). Crusoe quickly shoots 3 of the men, while the forth binds his own hands, to show he is no threat. Crusoe takes this man, at gunpoint, back to his home. Because he sees him as a savage, unfit to be given a proper name, he names him for the day of the week. He proceeds to use the man as a slave, even telling Friday that his name is Master, which Crusoe is called for the whole movie, except one scene. Friday himself breaks with Crusoe over the realization of what he is in Crusoe's eyes, and says he would rather die than live as a slave. He is referred to as a slave in one scene. Most communication is had while Friday has a gun pressed to his head or body, which he is told is imbued with White magic that only allows it to shoot black men.

Friday has his own perspective and agenda, but I think the important part is what Crusoe means in using the term "**My** man Friday". From Crusoe's perspective, Friday is an ignorant peon who he is tricking into doing his bidding so Crusoe can sit around reading all day, doing the "Master's work" of thinking. He tolerates Friday, but they are not meant to be equals. My man Friday seems to mean a slave, or at best, a lackey or errand-boy. I feel that this is a more correct interpretation of the phrase than "a person one can trust". As to whether it can mean a woman, that would be a "Gal Friday," but should have essentially the same meaning.

I wouldn't be surprised if the Cambridge or Oxford dictionaries went out of their way to avoid the "distasteful" subjects of slavery and prejudice, as many textbooks and reference materials have historically downplayed the importance and relevance of such topics.

Comment: Given the number of modern TV and movie adaptations of the Robinson Crusoe story, what makes you believe that this one version is that influential?

Comment: Even in the original book, which I have since studied up on, Crusoe named himself "Master" when teaching Friday English, and though Crusoe could have accepted him as a friend, he was always a servant. The book is not as stark in showing Crusoe as quick to kill out of misunderstanding, and he does not take Friday by force, but there is still a huge power differential that is firmly set in place and maintained by Crusoe. Even near the end of the book, Crusoe thinks of him "I began really to love the creature", not "the man". Crusoe was also slaver for a time before being castaway on the island

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site. I think there are a few problems with your answer. The term "man Friday" was in use before 1975 but nevertheless within the lifetime of people still alive today. Also you have only explained what the term meant in the Robinson Crusoe story, not what it means to people who use it today in an office context as mentioned in the question. And you haven't answered the original question about whether the term "woman Friday" is acceptable.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Actually, the original question is; what is the slang usage of the term "a Man Friday" in English conversation. The most upvoted answer defines the phrase by the book Robinson Crusoe, and my answer is redirecting what that book's definition of the term is, and the fullness of the dictionary definitions. The movie is from the 70's, when the expression was brought into household usage, and is a retelling of the book from 1719. You have no issue with the other answers, but feel mine is lacking? Why? I feel I have been very descriptive, and pointed to parts of the book and movie as references

Comment: @Rae Sauron :   It didn't have the prescriptively correct emphasis/perspective. 8~} +1 from me. especially for "gal Friday", feels better than "woman Friday". You thoroughly addressed OP's questions, accurately it seems.

Comment: The original question certainly did ask if the term can be used for a woman, and you didn't cover that. (Neither did the accepted answer.) You said in a comment that the term came into household use in the 70s - what references to you have to support that assertion? It was in use earlier than that - don't forget also the 1940 movie "His Girl Friday" which I think is certainly will known to my (still-living) parents' generation.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Indeed Google ngrams strongly suggests that the term [didn't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22man+Friday%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20man%20Friday%20%22%3B%2Cc0) gain currency in the 1970s (in fact possibly the reverse).

Comment: Why is an add-on question suddenly so important to you because I did not add it as part of my original answer? If that was THE question, then why was it in the last line, and preceded by "and"? This was an afterthought, not the point of the whole question. Either way, I edited that point into my answer an hour before your second post. I'm addressing the point of what the phrase really means, but people get struck deaf when you mention prejudice in connection with long-held icons or beliefs. This is why we "whitewash" things like this phrase, to erase what we don't want to accept of our past

Comment: And to that point, I don't see how a comedy movie that took the phrase from the source material would change the meaning, when the book is older, if you believe that matters, and the (Man Friday)movie is newer, if you believe that weighs heavier. Unless there is some evidence that this similarly-named comedy was so much bigger and popular than the Crusoe stories as to eclipse them.