# What does the title "Man Friday" mean?

Tags: phrases

I was reading this book Gujarat files and suddenly I came across this word Narendra Modi’s Man Friday (describing Amit Shah) What does this title mean? And also is the word 'title' I used correct word here in this context?

Comment: I think it's General Reference / common knowledge that ["Girl Friday" is a derivation of Robinson Crusoe's "Man Friday"](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-235716.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers One data point: native AmE speaker and I've (shamefully) never read Robinson Crusoe, nor heard the phrase "man Friday", nor knew what "girl Friday" meant (I had heard it in passing) before now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It comes from the novel **Robinson Crusoe** by Daniel Defoe:

> man Friday n. pl. men Friday or men Fridays An efficient, faithful
>   male aide or employee. [After Friday, a character in Robinson Crusoe,
>   a novel by Daniel Defoe.]

From the Free Dictionary online.  Also, from Wikipedia:

> Friday is one of the main characters of Daniel Defoe's 1719 novel
>   Robinson Crusoe. Robinson Crusoe names the man, with whom he cannot at
>   first communicate, Friday because they first meet on that day. The
>   character is the source of the expression "Man Friday", used to
>   describe a male personal assistant or servant, especially one who is
>   particularly competent or loyal. Current usage also includes "Girl
>   Friday".

Comment: Hi, Steven, I edited your answer. Please take a look. If you don't like it, you can roll it back.

Comment: Subservience, which is also an important part of the picture, is not adequately implied in *loyalty,* I think. Crusoe was white and Friday wasn't, so to Defoe and his readers subservience was natural to imagine. (Crusoe had even dabbled in the slave trade before ever becoming a castaway.) The expression involves *man* in the sense of *manservant* or valet.

Comment: "Gal/Guy Friday" help wanted ads, which were ads looking for personal assistants, were common in the classified sections of major newspapers in the 1970s and 80s. Another cultural reference is the classic movie "His Girl Friday" (1940) starring Cary Grant and Rosalind Russell.

Comment: Hmm. Where have i heard this before?  Oh, yeah: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294468/usage-of-the-slang-a-man-friday-in-english-conversation/294489#294489